# Login with Certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, certificate

I need a certificate login for my website. I am able to choose certificate and proceed to the website using connector tag in server.xml (tomcat 9). But I need a **sign in with certificate** button in the web page.I need to implement this using java . But I am unable to convert the functionality of the connector tag into java code.

Any Immediate Help will be Appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you - https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/  - - - when you attach to a https you use a certificate. Also you would use Java to make a certificate https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Generating-a-self-signed-SSL-certificate-using-the-Java-keytool-command?language=en_US

Comment: Actually, I created the certificate and imported it to my truststore. The thing I need is ....when I click the Sign in button the 'select certificate' should be prompt, then after selecting the certificate,the server checks whether the certificate is in truststore or not,if its is there...then it has to be stored in a database . Thats it!!... I have to implement this in java.